# What kind of wire terminator is this for computer power supply fan?

Tags: power-supply, wire, fan, wire-terminals

Trying to determine the style of wire-terminator used here so I can buy a few. What is this called? It's on the wires for a three-wire fan used in a desktop's power supply.

[image]

Comment: looks like someone pulled the contacts out of the connector shell ... is the connector shell glued to the motherboard?

Comment: I pulled them out of the connector shell. The connector was just going to the three-pin terminal for the fan.

Comment: The connector shell may help to identify the contacts you show - similar-looking contacts may not be compatible between manufacturers, or even between different connector families within one manufacturer.

Comment: @GrantCurell they are contacts specifically designed for that type of connector shell. They go with the shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Molex KK 254 Crimp Terminals :)

[Molex Link](https://www.molex.com/molex/search/partSearch?pQuery=&sType=s&query=2759)

[Digi-Key Link #1](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0008550102/172056)

[Digi-Key Link #2](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0008550131/512605?s=N4IgTCBcDaIAwA4CsS4EYDMaQF0C%2BQA)

Comment: Out of curiosity - how did you know this? Was this previous experience or did you just know how to look for it?

Comment: Previous experience :) Have put some fan headers on PCBs before so was easy to look up the part number and the mating connector + contacts.

Answer (score 2):

PC fans use the Molex ‘KK’ type.

Comment: The universal Molex crimper for these (63811-1000) is $63 which is shockingly reasonable for Molex.  You can also get pre-terminated 30cm jumpers with a crimped terminal on each end for about $1 and splice them onto the wires you need.